# iOS 7, Facebook Messenger app keeps crashing

Tags: ios, applications, crash, facebook

I was using my Facebook messenger app, and it suddenly crashed. I tried to open it again, but it kept crashing either instantly or after 20 seconds or so.

I've tried to turn it off and on, and delete and reinstall but its not working. Is there anything else I can do? What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 2):

An app that consistently crashes on launch is usually due to the device being out of memory (RAM, not system storage). There is a nice list of ways to cure that [here](http://www.maclife.com/article/howtos/fix_crashing_apps_your_iphone_and_ipad).

The next likely cause is bad data triggering a bug. You can often delete the app and redownload it to clear bad data files. Keep in mind if the app downloads data from the internet or has a backup / restore function.

Last resort is contacting the developer for specific recovery or triage steps based on their design of their app. Support links are provided in the App Store if you can’t find one searching the internet.

Comment: link appears to be broken

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- Uninstall the app
- Then go to Settings > General > Reset
- Tap on Reset all Settings (**not** the *Erase All Content and Settings)*
- After the reset is complete, re-install the app
- Start using the app again